# What are the Reserved/Predefined Environment Variables in GCP Compute Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

What are the predefined/reserved environment variables in GCP?

In general, it'd be great to have a list to reduce potential conflicts.

Comment: I have published an incomplete list [here](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-cloud-environment-variables/). If anyone knows of more, let me know via article comments or here as a comment/answer.